# Why doesn't my 'npm install --global yarn' work?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

After running `npm install --global yarn`, I get an output that says:

```
> yarn@1.22.18 preinstall C:\Users\(me)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)

C:\Users\(me)\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn -> C:\Users\(me)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
C:\Users\(me)\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarnpkg -> C:\Users\(me)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
+ yarn@1.22.18
updated 1 package in 0.389s
```

When I run "yarn serve" it tells me that 'yarn' is not recognized as a command.  I've tried this in powershell and CMD and neither works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ended up being a path issue.  I used `npm list -g` to reveal where yarn was installed. Then I searched for "Edit the environment variables" in Windows and added the containing folder to the PATH.

I also updated my node and npm to the latest versions before doing these steps.

Answer (score -1):

Just put --> `npm install -g yarn`

The problem is that you're installing nvm as root, and when npm runs the lifecycle scripts it downgrades the permissions, making it impossible to even run Node scripts, since the node binary can only be accessed by root.